# Does anyone know the violin song that Toshiya Miike plays after Kousei's performance in episode 13?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

Does anyone know the violin song that Toshiya Miike (Mikke-kun/-san) plays after Kousei's performance in episode 13? I wish I knew the exact time but I don't. I've searched everywhere trying to see if anyone figured it out or knew what it was but no luck. Help please?

Comment: FWIW I had the exact same question back when I saw _Your Lie in April_, and found the answer while skimming [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/2sjj52/spoilers_shigatsu_wa_kimi_no_uso_episode_13/) after searching for `your lie in april episode 13 soundtrack`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be:

**Elgar: Violin Sonata in E minor, Op 82 Vengerov**

Or **[エルガー： ヴァイオリン・ソナタ ホ短調 作品82 ヴェンゲーロフ]** if in Japanese.

Here is a link to the piece: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOutOaSMHZ4